# PHP/MySQL Batch Delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, batch-file

is there a way to batch up deletes for MySQL when using PHP (mysqli)?

With inserts you can do something like

```
insert into tbl (...) values (...) (...) (...) ...
```

is there any equivalent for deletes?

Comment: The equivalent would be `WHERE`: `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
delete from tbl where id IN (1,2,3)
```

OR

```
delete from tbl where id = 1 OR id = 2 OR email = 'admin@example.com'
```

you can make sure you delete the right data by doing select first...

ps: for the php,

```
<?
$ids = array(1,2,3);

$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")";
?>
```

or

```
<?
$deleteme = array("id = 1", "id = 2", "email = 'admin@example.com'");

$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $deleteme);
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `OR` like this, use `IN` instead.

Comment: Ah, ok, I should have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: ah, yeah, I forgot about `IN` .. will revise my answer

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, then:

- It does not really depend on PHP, it's purely up to the SQL statement used
- Usually, you delete rows based ON `WHERE X = Y` condition. So if you want to delete multiple rows, you would just extend the condition to `WHERE X = Y OR X = Z` or even `WHERE X IN (Y, Z, ..)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WHERE` clausole. For example:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE Id in (0,1,...,n)
```

Comment: that won't work, since the conditions are more complex than just one matching id

Comment: @Dexter have you read the "For example" string? Anyway, as you can see, everybody told you the same statement. There will be a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use In clause in delete statement, this is one of the best methods and you can pass thousands of ids in IN clause. I personally tested 25k ids and it's worked